# how to disable submit button on click and re-enable on the response in jquery forms plugin

Tags: php, jquery-forms-plugin

i want to be able to make the submit button in jquery form plugin disabled and then when the response is retrieved, it should become enable. i am trying thru the code below but as soon as in the onlick event i disabled the button it somehow stops the submission. although i am able to change the class of the button.

what am i doing wrong?

code is like this:

```
function timing(){
 d=Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
 $('input[name=timedate]').val(d);
 var btn1 = $('#post_global');  
 btn1.val('posting');
 btn1.removeClass('t_s').addClass('t_sDisabled');
 btn1.prop('disabled',true);    
  }

 (function() {
 $('form').ajaxForm({
dataType: 'json', 
beforeSubmit: validate,
success: processResponse

}); 
  })();  

 function processResponse(data) {
  document.getElementById('upfile').value = "";
  document.getElementById('fileinfo').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('txt1').value="post anything...";
   var status = $('#status');   
if(data.errors == ""){
    status.hide().html(data.htmlResponse).fadeIn(1000);
} else{
alert(data.errors);
    }
var btn2 = $('#post_global');   
btn2.val('post');
btn2.removeClass('t_sDisabled').addClass('t_s');    
btn2.prop('disabled',false);
  }
```

Comment: If using Google Chrome, you can press f12 and click on console. If it stops submission, it is likely you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I think you're looking for. If you want more, just comment what you want below:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
$('#btn2').attr("disabled", true);
//Do the request here
$('#btn2').attr("disabled", false);}
```

Possibly this?

```
function timing(){
 d=Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
 $('input[name=timedate]').val(d);
 var btn1 = $('#post_global');  
 btn1.val('posting');
 $('#btn2').attr("disabled", true);
  }

 (function() {
 $('form').ajaxForm({
dataType: 'json', 
beforeSubmit: validate,
success: processResponse

}); 
  })();  

 function processResponse(data) {
  document.getElementById('upfile').value = "";
  document.getElementById('fileinfo').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('txt1').value="post anything...";
   var status = $('#status');   
if(data.errors == ""){
    status.hide().html(data.htmlResponse).fadeIn(1000);
} else{
alert(data.errors);
    }
var btn2 = $('#post_global');   
btn2.val('post');
$('#btn2').attr("disabled", false);
  }
```

Comment: u mean i should add that ajax form function in the onclick event? i'm not sure ajaxForm would work this way

Comment: can u suggest something to my code? and i still dont know the reason why it freezes submission on changing the disable property to true?

Comment: Don't consider is "prop", its `$('#btn2').attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: thats a whole lot of change, almost rewriting my code. could you suggest edits in mine and not suggest to change the whole thing entirely, i'm new to jquery and with a lot  of effort i;ve made everything working in my current code except for what i asked in the question

Comment: Could you possibly give me a demo link?

Comment: thanks anyway, i cant go around doing the overhaul coz of time constraint. maybe,i'l have to settle with changing classes and skip the disabling button functionality. thanks alot again

Comment: With demo link, I could attempt to find the error, fix it, make it working, and post it here.

Comment: i'm really sorry i cant put it up on a link. as it is, i dnt have a domain and also, it'l take time to put evrything together somewhere. but i appreciate your willingness to help, i'm grateful.

Comment: Okay, sorry I couldn't help your situation.